# How do I place a div above an input with a certain value?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of buttons. I want to have a div show above the active input. I have tried to reproduce an example. -> [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-cookies-12h8j?file=/src/App.js)

```
 <p ref={textRef}>c</p>
      {data.letters.map((value, i) => (
        <input
          key={i}
          type="button"
          value={value}
          ref={(el) => (inputRef.current[i] = el)}
          className={data.active === value ? "active" : ""}
        />
      ))}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do conditional rendering .  [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

```
 <div className="App">
      {data.letters.map((value, i) => {
        
        return (
        <React.Fragment key={i}>
        {data.active === value && <div>{value}</div> }
        <input
          type="button"
          value={value}
          ref={(el) => (inputRef.current[i] = el)}
          className={data.active === value ? "active" : ""}
        />
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      )}
    </div>
```